# JavaScript for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

In JavaScript I am aware of a number of different ways to iterate over each element in an array. At present my favorite is the `array.forEach(function(entry){})` style but I know there is also the traditional `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` as well as `for (entry in array)` and JQuery's `$.each()` method.

My question is this:
given a list of variable length eg: `var arr = ['abc', 'xyz', '123', ...]` what's the best way to loop over each element?

Comment: Don't use `for (entry in array)` for arrays. It's specifically for iterating over objects and you can get into trouble if you use it for arrays.

Comment: Note that `array.forEach()` is not available in older browsers (IE8 and below, Firefox before 1.5)

Comment: With jQuery you obviously have the added overhead of adding in jQuery. I prefer a tradition `for-loop`.

Comment: [relevant reading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9329446/497418)

Comment: nobody remembers of `while`? cause the for is based on `while` and `foreach` on `for`....so instead to do 2-3 operations you can do just 1 and buy some extra performance

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/12/06/best-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/). Very informative

Comment: http://jsperf.com/123453svfs

Comment: by my experience , the best is :

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)

because you write your functions and if some day you want to merge or rewrite your functions in another language like java, C++ or php you 'll have just a little changes.


unlike jquery has his own language.

Comment: Answering your new question: You can use the `for(var i=0; i<5; i++)` for read your array or `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance I would favor:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

For ease of use I generally use:

```
array.forEach(function(entry){})
```

Or for DOM elements I prefer jQuery: `$.each()`

Comment: What makes for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) better for performance?

Comment: @nettux443: When you use other objects to iterate over them, like jQuery, you will always have performance loss. `for` is just the most bare metal way of iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Is not better one than other.

The for each loops are when you don't know how many items are in the array. `array.forEach(function(entry){})` or `$.each()`

The basic loop (for) is when you know the especific number of items in the array. `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)`. And this is less load for the process.

Comment: you can say for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++). foreach is great if you don't have an easy way to know how many items are in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

`for (entry in array)` is the one that is the most different in that it is a way to iterate over properties of an object, and not items in a list. It's not like a traditional foreach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in